# Ошибка Server not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

Я размещаю  вэб приложение на сервер с ос `Windows Server 2019`. Но при обращении с серверу работает только `https://localhost/`. Если же ввожу имя на этой же машине `https://cktjournal.ru/` , то получаю ошибку `Server not found`. Приложение разработано на .Net Core 3.1. [Отюда](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) на сервер  установил `Hosting Bundle`. `Firewall` отключен. В чем может быть причина? В настройках IIS Bindins прописаны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `cktjournal.ru: Non-existent domain` - такого домена не существует. Вы забыли его купить?

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! Сделайте как ответ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы домен второго уровня заработал, его надо купить у регистратора (их несколько выбирайте любого) и делегировать на DNS, либо на свой, либо на хостера, в зависимости от ваших потребноестей.

И далее уже с того DNS указать публичный IP своего сервера, на который должны идти запросы при обращении к домену. И вот тогда все заработает.